# Add record using own button from JS (Odoo)?

Tags: javascript, odoo

I'm making my own list using the `list_editable_renderer.js` file and extending the `one2many` widget according to my needs, now I want to put an add button when creating a record in the `attribute_line_ids` field, currently Odoo saves when the save button is clicked but it What do I want to save when I click on my new button

[image]

My xml:

```
 <field name="attribute_line_ids" widget="table_one2many" context="{'show_attribute': False}" attrs="{'invisible':[('has_variants','=', False)]}" >
                                            <tree string="Variants" editable="top" multi_edit="1" options="{'only_one_row': 'True', 'add_record_button': 'True'}" >
                                                <field name="attribute_id" attrs="{'readonly': [('id', '!=', False)]}" string="Opción"/>
                                                <field name="value_ids" string="Valores (Sepáralos con un tab)" widget="many2many_tags_variaciones_bb" options="{'no_create_edit': False}" context="{'default_attribute_id': attribute_id, 'show_attribute': False}"/>
                                            </tree>
 </field>
```

My button action is:

```
'click tr .o_list_record_add': '_onAddIconClick',
```

and the function:

```
_onAddIconClick: function(event){
        this._onAddRecord(event,true)
},
```

My error is:

```
web.assets_backend.js:1144 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

I am not sure if it is the correct way or if you can guide me I would appreciate it.

Note: Odoo14

Comment: Nope, you can not save the data on your button because that's not the odoo framework does, the one2many table concept is like we need to link those data with the parent , If there is no parent record than how should you link this? this is not a better solution for your requirements, please find another solution.

Comment: @Saumil I have the record, the parent's id, the context, with that I have two options, one to send the data to the write method or the two to my own method and save the data individually; In conclusion if it can be done !, I am trying to go with the first option but I get stuck in how to generate the domain, since with option 2 I do not have that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Front JS new button:

```
 _onAddIconClick: function(event){
        var self = this;
        this._rpc({
            model: record.model,
            method: 'save_record',
            context: {
                    model: record.model,
                    record: record,
                },
        }).then(function () {
            self._render()
        });

    }
```

in the backend I collect the context and apply your criteria

```
@api.model
def save_record(self):
    record = self.env.context['record']
    pt = self.env['product.template'].sudo().browse(record['context']['params']['id'])
    if pt:
        attribute_id_rec = record['data']['attribute_id']
        value_ids_rec = record['data']['value_ids']
        obj ={}
        obj['has_variants'] = True
        value_ids = {}
        value_ids['attribute_id'] = attribute_id_rec['res_id']
        value_ids['value_ids'] = [[6, False, value_ids_rec['res_ids']]]
        lista = [[0, record['ref'], value_ids]]
        obj['attribute_line_ids'] = lista
        return pt.write(obj)
```